# Python find two max amplitudes from uneven sinewave and plot cropped wave

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, waveform

Does anyone has experience in Python how to find two max points from sinewave and then crop the cycle from point to point that it contains all the cycle waveform that is occurring in-between and the two max point also shown.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Generate random uneven sine wave
    np.random.seed(0)
    t = np.linspace(0, 3, num=1000)  # Time vector
    frequencies = np.random.rand(5) * 10  # Random frequencies
    amplitudes = np.random.rand(5) * 2  # Random amplitudes
    phase_offsets = np.random.rand(5) * 2 * np.pi  # Random phase offsets

    y = np.zeros_like(t)  # Initialize wave
    for i in range(len(frequencies)):
        y += amplitudes[i] * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequencies[i] * t + phase_offsets[i])

    # Find indices of first and second maximum amplitudes
    max_idx1 = np.argmax(y)
    y[max_idx1] = 0  # Set first max amplitude to 0 to find second max
    max_idx2 = np.argmax(y)

    # Check if first and second max amplitudes are distinct
    if max_idx1 == max_idx2:
        print("First and second maximum amplitudes are the same.")
    else:
        # Plot the entire wave
        plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
        plt.plot(t, y)
        plt.title('Random Uneven Sine Wave')
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

        # Plot the cropped wave between first and second maximum amplitudes
        plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
        plt.plot(t[max_idx1:max_idx2+1], y[max_idx1:max_idx2+1])
        plt.title('Cropped Wave')
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

        plt.tight_layout()  # Add padding between subplots
        plt.show()  # Show the plot
```

Comment: For the second subplot use `plt.plot(t, y)` and then set the xlim: `plt.xlim(0.5, 2.0)` for example.